# How to find a process going rogue on Linux?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I'm running a Linux box AWS with Apache and MySQL (Linux servername 5.15.0-1022-aws #26-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 13 12:59:25 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux). Every few days I can see in the AWS console that the CPU spikes up to 100% and I can't SSH into the box anymore. It is still pingable, but no other connectivity seems to be possible (e.g. HTTPS).

I was trying to catch the rogue process by running

```
ps -eo pcpu,pid,user,args | sort -k 1 -r | head -10 >> proc.txt
```

in an endless loop and printing the top 10 processes (CPU load wise) to a textfile every 10 seconds, but the most spikes I see are going up to 15% for individual processes. According to the AWS console, the spike does last for a longer time than 10 seconds, so I think I should be able to catch it somehow.Unfortunately, I always have to forcefully stop the server and the restart it, because otherwise I can't connect back in.

Any suggestions on how I can find out on what's going on?
Thanks.

**UPDATE:**
Here is the code that let's a PHP page query the mySQL server:

```
<?php
function DBquery($qry) {
  $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "<mysql-userid>", "<mysql-password>", "<DBname>");
  $results = $mysqli->query($qry);
  $mysqli->close();
  return $results;
}

<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Results</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
Here are your results:<p>

<table>
<?php
    $results = DBquery("SELECT team,venue,datetime FROM tbl_schedule WHERE venue='".$_POST['venue']."';");
    while ($row=$results->fetch_array()) {
        echo "<tr><td>".$row['datetime']."</td><td>".$row['team']."    </td><td>".$row['venue']."</td></tr>";
    }
?>
</table>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: When you can see 100% on AWS console, from MySQL Command Prompt, SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;  post the TEXT output for analysis.  As you know, endless loops just aggravate the problem.  Could you post the source code responsible for 'Connect', 'Process' and 'Close connection"?  We may see where you are not CLOSING your connections to free resources.

Comment: the problem is that I am unable to do anything on the server once the it hits the 100%. I am unable to initiate a new SSH connection, and even existing ones become dead. The only thing I can do is to "pull the plug" and start over, then it works again for 1-2 days until it spikes again. I should also add that this server is a dev server, so it is not used in production, which means that the last few times when the spike occurred there was no active HTTPS or mySQL communication/tasks ongoing as it was in the middle of the night and I did not create any cron jobs to fire off a task.

Comment: Could you post from your DEV server, the source code responsible for 'Connect', 'Process' and 'Close connection"? We may see where you are not CLOSING your connections to free resources.

Comment: On AWS even in the middle of the night, 12 times an hour a com_flush is initiated.

Comment: thanks for following up, I provided the update above.

Comment: Could you provide the URL to the example code used to develop the code you have posted?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I was traveling.... sorry. but I am not exactly sure what you are asking for...  I put this code together and it is hosted on an internal server (even though it's running on AWS), so there is on external accessible URL

Comment: Looking for the boiler plate / template / example code you used for the design of your function to 'Connect', 'Process', 'Close' the connection.  Wondering if the example you used had any error handling.  You code does not have any error handling that I can see.

Comment: no, it actually was a copy/paste job from some examples i found online; these are my first attempts on trying to get php to talk to mysql. So, there is no error checking in just yet. This is why I am so puzzled about the spikes, since there is no real activity going on.

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysqli/mysqli_use_result.htm 
you may find this url helpful to guide you in finding a useful pattern. 
My observation, should be your last consideration - does it make sense to close the connection before retrieving the results?